# django - relation between server tags, server and the post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm creating a reddit clone app, There are 3 servers, each server has its own set of tags(e.g., for food server: burger, pizza,...)
and each server can have multiple posts(just like Reddit).

so how can I make it so that the user can choose between tags when creating a new post?
user should only be able to choose on of the tags dedicated to the server which the post is going to be posted on.

I've made a `ServerTag` model to save tags when creating a new **server**:

```
class ServerTag(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    primary_color = ColorField(default = '#ffff')
    secondary_color = ColorField(default = '#ffff')
    is_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name} --> r/{self.server}'
```

`Server` model:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    about = models.TextField(default='about')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='server')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='servers/pic/')
    header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='servers/header-pic/')
    members_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    online_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    required_karma = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and `Post` Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_type_choices = [('text', 'text'), ('video', 'video'), ('image', 'image'), ('link','link')]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, default='slug')
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    text_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/images/', null=True, blank=True)
    image_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='posts/videos/', null=True, blank=True)
    video_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=post_type_choices, default='text')
    votes_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(ServerTag, on_delete=models.CASCADE , default=1) //connected to the ServerTags model
```

Currently `Post` has a tag field which shows all tags created in all servers, Though I only want to show tags dedicated to the server which the user is posting on.

Comment: Are you using dedicated databases for each server?

Comment: no there is only one database.